# appending different data to the end of each line in csv file

Tags: powershell

I need to add text to the end of the header in a text/csv file and then add other text (date) at the end of each line below the header.  Adding the text part is working fine but it's the exporting to a csv that's not working as expected.

The expected output is (bold text is the added text);
"Folder Name","Files","Folders","Size","Comment"**,"ReportDate"**
"\\server\share\folder","2,029,756","819,527","1,785,490,958,735"," "**,"1/10/2020"**

Instead I'm getting;
"Length"
"61"
"74"
"88"
"118"

```
$Path = "C:\temp\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $Path -filter '*.csv'
ForEach ($file in $files)
{
    $datetmp = $file.PSChildName.Substring(0,10)
    $datetmp = $datetmp.split("_")
    $date = $datetmp[1] + "/" + $datetmp[2] + "/" + $datetmp[0]

    $Fullpath = $Path + $file

    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$content = Get-Content $Fullpath #| %{"$_," + $date}
    $rptinsert = @()

    for ($i=0; $i -lt ($content.Count); $i++)
    {
        if ($i -eq 0)
        {
            $rptinsert += $content[$i] + ",""ReportDate"""
        }
        else
        {
            $rptinsert += $content[$i] + ",`"$date`""
        }
    }


    $Report = $Path + $file.PSChildName.Substring(0, 10) + "-FileSizes2.csv"
    $rptinsert | Export-Csv -path $Report -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

I'm sure there are shorter methods to perform the some of my lines as well, just not looking for that right now. ;-)

Comment: To use `Export-Csv` the way you are expecting, you need to be inputting objects with property/value pairs. You are piping in strings. The only property a string has is `Length`. I would use `Import-Csv` to read the files, modify the returned values, and then `Export-Csv` to output the changed objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `Export-Csv` the way you are expecting, you need to be inputting objects with property/value pairs. You are piping in strings. The only property a string has is `Length`. I would use `Import-Csv` to read the files, modify the returned values, and then `Export-Csv` to output the changed objects. Below is a blueprint that will work:

```
$Path = "C:\temp\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $Path -filter '*.csv'
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $datetmp = $file.Name.Substring(0,10).Split('_')
    $date = $datetmp[1],$datetmp[2],$datetmp[0] -join '/'
    $content = Import-Csv $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ReportDate' -Value $date -PassThru
    $content | Export-Csv -Path ($Path + $file.Name.Substring(0, 10) + "-FileSizes2.csv") -NoType
}
```

The output of [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) is a collection of custom objects with property names that match the header line of the CSV file. Since ***it appears*** you want the same value added to every line of a CSV file, you can just run one [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7) command. If each line needs a different value, then you will need to loop through each line and run an `Add-Member` command.

`Add-Member` allows for adding different member types to an object. In your case, you want to add a `NoteProperty` type with a value.

Once the updates are complete to one CSV's contents, you can pipe those results into [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7). `-NoType` prevents an additional header line with type information from the output.

Comment: Thank you @AdminOfThings.  

Only thing I had to do was in the Import-CSV instead of using $file I had to incorporate $file.PSPath to get it to work.